# Access denied for user after migration from different site collection

Tags: 2013, migration, forms-authentication

I'm working on migrating users from a forms based authenticated (not windows) site collection to another.

Even though, all the users and all the permissions have been copied, an access denied error is thrown as soon as any user logs in (user has read permission.) I've checked that everything is checked in and published. Also, checking permissions shows none for any migrated user.

Am I missing something here? I just copied permissions using a tool and I expected it to work...

Has anybody encountered anything like this before? Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. It was due to a silly mistake. The membership providers of the two site collections were different.

The user I migrated from the source was using a different provider. Changing the membership provider name on the target to match that of the source fixed the issue.